# How do format each comment in an excel spreadsheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to format all the existing comments in my active excel spreadsheet. I have been trying to use the following code:

```
Public Sub FormatNote()
 If Not ActiveCell.Comment Is Nothing Then
  OrganizeElements
 End If
End Sub

Public Sub FormatNotes()
 For Each ????? In ActiveSheet.Comments
  OrganizeElements
 Next
End Sub

Public Sub OrganizeElements()
 ActiveCell.Comment.Shape.TextFrame.AutoSize = True
 'And many other formats
End Sub
```

Formatting a single comment works. However, formatting all the comments does not. What do I use after the "For Each"? Originally, I was using "Dim Note as Comment" and then using "For Each Note..." and that seemed to work OK but it had other problems. I am trying not to use variables until I understand the code more fundamentally. How do I refer to each or all existing comments in the active sheet and then do something with them?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This would be the approach you're looking for.

Have in mind that you're working with the ActiveSheet object

**Code:**

```
Public Sub FormatNotes()
    Dim targetComment As Comment

    For Each targetComment In ActiveSheet.Comments
        OrganizeElements targetComment
    Next targetComment

End Sub

Public Sub OrganizeElements(ByVal targetComment As Comment)
    targetComment.Shape.TextFrame.AutoSize = True
    'And many other formats
End Sub
```

Let me know if it works

Comment: Thank you Ricardo! It does work. However, it broke another part of my code which was a Sub to format a single note. I eventually solved it with a Set function.